# Failing to Upload JSON Postgresql Database Backup to New Django Heroku App via loaddata

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am upgrading an old app to a new app on Heroku (Python 3.7 Django 2.2). Locally, I was able to successfully upload json database backup fixture and it works great. I've created a new app with no problems, but when I upload the database backup fixture to the new Heroku app the process just ends after several seconds and the data is not uploaded. I am given no errors.

This is my command:

```
heroku run python manage.py loaddata db-back1.json
```

The response:

```
Running python manage.py loaddata db-back1.json on ⬢ app-name... up, run.6706 (Free)
```

Shortly, after it just ends the process with no error.

Notes and things I've tried:

- My json fixture file is 300mb, so it's quite large. It took several minutes to upload on my local instance. Do I need to upload to S3 first?
- I've upgraded the app to standard on heroku and and the url of the database has been updated correctly and is set to the right database, though the response keeps including (Free).
- To be clear, the Heroku app is working successfully, it just has no data. Further, I was able to get the app and dataload working successfully on my local version. This leads me to believe there is some requirement I am missing with Heroku.

Are there size limits or other obvious things that I am overlooking that would explain the upload process to ending abruptly with no error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if anyone out there is wondering, Heroku doesn't time out but there is some file limit. My 300mb JSON file was likely the cause of the problem. I used JSON because it worked locally. Did some more research and instead of creating a JSON file, I created a .sql file and was able to compress it to 20mb. With the .sql file, I was able to avoid using the loaddata function and did pg:restore as outlined in [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) and worked perfectly.